# preserveDrawingBuffer false - is it worth the effort?

Tags: javascript, performance, webgl

When using preserveDrawingBuffer for our context we need to take care of clearing the drawing buffer by our self. I use this technique in my app.

I read some article that says - setting this flag to false can get better performances.

In my app when setting to false, in some cases i need to take care of clearing the front buffer by myself because when no drawing is happening we can still see what was drawn before.

My question, is it worth now to turn my app upside down and covering all the cases in order to get better performances? Is it really so much improving ?

Is there any demo that shows the different in performances when this flag is true (and performing `gl.clear(..)`) compares to false ?

Comment: In good video cards, clearing is done zone by zone with a single bit by zone (expl 64X64 'tile'). So a good implementation of webgl will only clear those flags, not write a bunch of zeros in memory. I'd bet performance gain is very small with preserveDrawingBuffer to true or false (rq : i never saw clear() in my profiles). Hoping you'll have a more complete answer.

Answer (score 36):

I know this has been answered elsewhere but I can't find it so ....

```
preserveDrawingBuffer: false
```

means WebGL can swap buffers instead of copy buffers.

WebGL canvases have 2 buffers. The one you're drawing to and the one being displayed. When it comes time to draw the webpage WebGL has 2 options

1. Copy the drawing buffer to the display buffer.

   This operation is slower obviously as copying thousands or millions pixels is not
   a free operation
2. Swap the two buffers.

   This operation is effectively instant as nothing really needs to happen except to swap
   the contents of 2 variables.

Whether WebGL swaps or copies is up to the browser and various other settings but if `preserveDrawingBuffer` is `false` WebGL can swap, if it's `true` it can't.

If you'd like to see a perf difference I'd suggested trying your app on mobile phone. Make sure antialiasing is off too since antialiasing requires a *resolve* step which is effectively copy operation.

Comment: My app is not running on mobiles (at least for now) but my clients graphic cards are very cheap, so I've decided to go for it and check my app for all the bugs `preserveDrawingBuffer=false` will cause and maybe get some better performances there. Thanks allot

Comment: After working and covering all the cases, I've managed to release some version with `preserveDrawingBuffer=false`. personally i didn't see any change in performance, but, at my clients with their poor graphic card, they say that there was great performances improvement. Just wanted to share it

Comment: I set up a test and checked on low mobiles and laptops to get a quantitative feedback. The difference is very small. Experience used : on https://preservedrawingbuffer-test.surge.sh, put the grass fullscreen, increase the grass seeds in the GUI until there is a significant and stable FPS drop, then toggle preserveDrawingBuffer : a grey clear color switch confirms the canvas switch. Report perf change. For me on low mobiles and laptops, at 20FPS, I get a difference of 1FPS. Nothing was noticeable above 20FPS.

Comment: Every device is different. Apple is the one that asked for the `preserveDrawingBuffer` feature. Before they asked for it WebGL was the same as Canvas, just always copying. They claimed it was faster to swap on iOS and would be much slower to copy. That was in 2009. It's now 2018 so maybe less true on a 9years newer phone? Or maybe Safari changed so it no longer takes advantage of the speed up.

Comment: I did some tests on my modern laptop and found out that setting `preserveDrawingBuffer` to true didn't reduce performance enough for it to be measured by the code while a user is rotating a 3D WebGL object, nor was the difference visually noticeable

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, `preserveDrawingBuffer=true` means WebGL has to flush the pipeline between frames. OpenGL drawing isn't synchronous, and so drawing commands can be still in the pipeline when you finish your frame.

This would be equivalent to placing a flush at the end of your render loop. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/flush

So that is why the results can vary a lot. If your GPU has buffered a lot of commands, then it will then the program will be forced to stop while all the GPU commands are executed. 
However, if your GPU is fast, then there might not be much in the buffer, and so things simply continue.

I've seen cases where placing a flush call at the end of the render loop dropped the Fps by 50%.

I would avoid `preserveDrawingBuffer=true` because it will hurt performance when you need it most.

Comment: `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` has no relationship to `gl.flush`. It only has a relationship to swapping buffers vs copying buffers. It was specifically added to the spec at the request of Apple who claimed swapping buffers would be much faster on iOS. Also `gl.flush` should have no effect on framerate. It's `gl.finish` that might have an effect. `gl.flush` just means "be aware of all the commands I've issued so far" where as `gl.finish` means "execute all the commands I've issued so far and don't return until they are complete"